# YML - Fixitures ID problems in Symfony 1.4.12

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, yaml, fixtures

I have the follwing fixiture file:

```
Category:
   webDev:
      name: Development Web
   webDesign:
      name: Web Desing
   Autres:
      name: Autres

Post:
   Post1:
      Category: webDev
      title: Ceci est un Test 1
      content: TEST
   Post2:
      Category: webDesign
      title: Ceci est un Test 2
      content: TEST
   Post3:
      Category: Autres
      title: Ceci est un Test 3
      content: TEST
```

The problem is that webDev is not recognized and the id is not automatically seted.

I don't want to use like that:

```
 Post1:
      category_id: 1
      title: Ceci est un Test 1
      content: TEST
```

But I want to use the name of the `webDev`, `webDesign` or `Autres` categories names. Is working and I have no error when I run:

```
./symfony doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation --and-load
```

However, when I look in MySQL database instead of the category `id` I get `NULL`. Why? Where is the error?

Here is my `schema.yml`

```
Category:
 tableName: categories
 columns:
  name: string(100)

Post:
 tableName: posts
 actAs:
  Timestampable: ~
  Sluggable:
   fields: [title]
 columns:
  category_id: integer
  title: string(100)
  content: text
 relations:
  Category:
   type: one
   foreignType: many
   local: id
   foreign: id
```

Comment: could you provide your schema for post and category?

Comment: I have update the question with my schema.yml

Comment: I think if you're defining "category_id" in Post, then your "local" ID should be "category_id" for the Category relation, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Flask Feel free to submit that as an answer; I was just butting in after you had the smart idea of looking at the schema, which was the important bit :)

Comment: @Matt Gibson you are right, this was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your schema, the foreign key will bet set to post.id instead of post.category_id.

try `local: category_id` instead of `local: id`